# $2021^{\text{st}}$ term of a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Q. Let sequence ${a_{n}}$ satisfy $$a_{1} = 1, a_{2}=4, a_{3}=5 $$ and $$ a_{n}+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}=n^2$$ $$\forall  n \geq 4 $$ Then find the sum of the digits of $ a_{2021}$ .

**My attempt**: The given sequence isn't making any progression . So I tried to calculate the furthur terms of the series and tried to get a possible sequence for the terms. However I was unsuccessful in that! Then I attempt to make a possible sequence for the sum of the digits of the further terms in the series, which got ruined too! Now I have no clue how to get on with that problem! I think forming a function of n as a difference of two terms would help but please could you suggest how to make it? Please help.

Answer (score 9):

For $n\geq 4$ we have:
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n-3}=(a_{n+1}+a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})-(a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3})$$
$$=(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$$
So that
$$a_{2021}=(2\cdot 2021 -1)+(2\cdot 2017-1)+\dots+(2\cdot5-1)+a_1 $$

I think you can take it from here?

Comment: Done! Sorry for the late reply! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For $n\geq 5$

$a_n+(n-1)^2 =a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}=$

$=n^2+a_{n-4}$

so

$a_n=a_{n-4}+2n-1$

and in the case $n=2021$ you have that

$a_{2021}=2n-1+\sum_{k=1}^{504} (2(n-4k)-1)+a_5=$

$505(2n-1)-8\sum_{k=1}^{504}k+a_5=$

$=505(2n-1)-8\frac{504\cdot 505}{2}+a_5=$

$=505(2n-1-4\cdot 504)+a_5$

Comment: n=2021, (n-5):4=504

Answer (score 2):

The *homogeneous* linear recurrence
$$ x_n = -x_{n-1} - x_{n-2} - x_{n-3} $$
with $x_0=1, x_{<0}=0$ is easily solved by direct calculation and gives the nice result
$$ (h_n)_n = (1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, \ldots) $$

You want to solve an *inhomogeneous* recurrence
$$ a_n = -a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} - a_{n-3} + c_n $$
The solution of that is the sum of shifted versions of the homogeneous solution,  scaled by the $c_n$s:
$$ a_n = \sum_{k\le n} c_k h_{n-k} $$

We already know the $c_n$s for $n\ge 4$, namely $c_n=n^2$, and we can find the first $c_n$s such that the known initial values of $a_n$ come out right:
$$ c_1 = 1 \qquad c_2 = 5 \qquad c_3 = 10 $$
(though $c_2$ and $c_3$ end up not mattering).
Putting this together we have
$$ \begin{align} a_{2021} &= c_{2021}-c_{2020} + c_{2017}-c_{2016} + \cdots + c_5 - c_4 + c_1 
\\&= 2021^2-2020^2 + 2017^2-2016^2 + \cdots + 5^2 - 4^2 + 1 \\&=
(2\cdot 2020+1) + (2\cdot 2016+1) + \cdots + (2\cdot 4+1) + 1 \end{align}
$$
and this finite arithmetic series is easy to sum.

Comment: Good to have this explained even though the easy summability of the "convolution" depends on the special form of the homogeneous solution (leading to Adam's +1 solution).

Comment: What is amazing to show is $a_n=\frac{1}{4} \left(1+n (n+3)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-5 \cos \left(\frac{\pi
    n}{2}\right)\right)$

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici .Wow! That's interesting! I never thought $a_{n}$ would come out a function of n .

Comment: @CreepAnonymous. I was almost sure that it could even be simple. I started writing $a_n=b_n+\alpha+\beta n+\gamma n^2$; then compute what is required to make a simple linear recurrence relation and so on. I had fun and I thank you for that !